# Why does SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER('E') return 0?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

According to [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html), TRY_TO_NUMBER should return NULL when passed a non-numeric value.  However, when passing the string 'E', the function returns a 0.

```
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER('E');
```

[Result showing 0 instead of expected NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USjdK.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because there is an implicit zero in front and after it:

```
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER('E'),
    TRY_TO_NUMBER('1E2'),
    TRY_TO_NUMBER('0E'),
    TRY_TO_NUMBER('0E0');
```

gives:

| TRY_TO_NUMBER('E') | TRY_TO_NUMBER('1E2') | TRY_TO_NUMBER('0E') | TRY_TO_NUMBER('0E0') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 |

probably much like `010.0` and `10` and 10.0` all parse to the same thing, the zero's are not required.

But it does seems like a failure of the parser.

Answer (score 2):

This can be overcome by passing an optional format parameter 'TM9' which specifies that you're NOT expecting scientific notation.

```
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER('E','TM9'),
    TRY_TO_NUMBER('1E2','TM9'),
    TRY_TO_NUMBER('0E','TM9'),
    TRY_TO_NUMBER('0E0','TM9')
```

All of those now successfully return NULL, as I'm assuming you want them to.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you're doing, you may also like Snowflake's [`RLIKE` comparison operator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike) which is like `LIKE` but allows regular expressions (regex):

```sql
SELECT
    '0' RLIKE '[0-9]',  -- True
    '1' RLIKE '[0-9]',  -- True
    '2' RLIKE '[0-9]',  -- True
    'A' RLIKE '[0-9]',  -- False
    'E' RLIKE '[0-9]'   -- False
;
```

Note that regex is computationally more expensive, so the `TRY_TO_NUMBER()` function will probably be more performant than this