# Default format for to_numeric function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the default format for the `to_numeric` function?

Looking through the documentation for [`to_numeric`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_decimal) the `format` argument is optional. However, it does not say what the default format is if left empy.

Looking at the [SQL Format Models](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models) it seems like the [Default Formats for Parsing](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models#default-formats-for-parsing) are `TM9`/`TME`.

However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71150181/why-does-select-try-to-numbere-return-0) SO question seems to imply that the default is not `TM9`.

How would I replicate the default behavior of `to_numeric` by explicitly passing in a input value for `format`?

Looking through the documentation, I would exect a default value to be given.

Answer (score 0):

[Default Formats for Parsing](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models#default-formats-for-parsing)

> The list of formats used for automatic optimistic string conversion (i.e. for strings which are automatically recognized as numeric) **is the union of all the formats in the above table of default input formats.**

> [Alternate, Automatic, and Default Formats](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models#alternate-automatic-and-default-formats)
>
> **When parsing strings, it is possible to specify multiple alternative formats by separating format strings with the | character. The string is successfully parsed if it matches any one format.** If the input string matches multiple formats, any format will be used for the conversion.

> [TO_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_decimal#returns)
>
> - If the precision is not specified, then it defaults to 38.
> - If the scale is not specified, then it defaults to 0.

```
select expr, to_number(expr, 'TM9|TME') 
from (select ('12.3456') union select('1E10')) as sub(expr);
```

To sum up:

```
to_number(expr)
<->
to_number(expr, 'TM9|TME', 38, 0)
```